# Importing Safari reading list to Pocket

Tags: terminal, script

I'd like to pull (long) my safari reading list into Pocket. Searching StackExchange/Google suggests the script [here](https://gist.github.com/arcadia168/0bade46a6bb720395f56#file-exportsafarireadinglist-sh) (also pasted below), but when I run it, it says `line 19: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

I have no clue about these files, so any advice would be appreciated!

Script follows (I obviously replaced both instances of myemailaddress@gmail.com with my own email address)

```
#!/bin/bash
# Script to export Safari's reading list into a text file, then import this into Pocket or Evernote (or any service with a "email in content" feature).

# First take all of Safari's Reading List items and place them in a text file.
/usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 -o - ~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist | grep -E  -o '<string>http[s]{0,1}://.*</string>' | grep -v icloud | sed -E 's/<\/{0,1}string>//g' > readinglistlinksfromsafari.txt

# Now loop over each of those URls within that text file and add them to pocket.
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo $line
/usr/sbin/sendmail -i -f myemailaddress@gmail.com add@getpocket.com <<END
Subject: $line
From: myemailaddress@gmail.com
To: add@getpocket.com

$line
END
done < readinglistlinksfromsafari.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you export bookmarks from Safari, it now includes your reading list in that export. You can then import the resulting HTML file to Pocket. [Import link here](https://getpocket.com/import/browser) (log in first). Some discussion [here](https://help.getpocket.com/article/1133-importing-into-pocket). So no need to try to use out of date scripts like the one I posted.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking at the original file, and you have to remove all spaces from the start of each line, starting with second line.

Or just copy paste the code from you question, because it already has all spaces deleted (probably Glorfindel, who edited your answer did this)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I no longer get the error message, but it doesn't seem to do anything. It definitely does't send 200 emails to add@getpocket.com. The reasdinglistlinksfromsafari.txt file it creates is empty - so I think it's not getting further than line 4. Any further thoughts/advice?!

Comment: On my machine, `~/Library/Safari/Bookmarks.plist` is not readable by the user, you have to use `sudo`, you should run the script with `sudo` I think

Comment: Thanks. I've tried that, i.e. writing sudo sh in terminal, and then dragging in the file from finder. It runs, in that it creates the txt file, but that file is still empty. Any other thoughts/advice?!